# cause a menu to expand from an HTML TabBar using VBA

Tags: html, vba, automation, tabbar

I have what I think should not be difficult situation. I need to "click" on a TabBar in IE 11 using VBA automation. When you click the drop down arrow with your mouse a small "menu" expands from it with a few fields that you can input text & search the results, etc. I cannot however get this effect with VBA. I've succeeded in hightlighting the area I want to click on with .focus but .click does not trigger the right result. The overall "button" has a left side & right side. My down arrow is on the right. i've tried I think every element I can. Here is part of the HTML of the website

```html
<a
    class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small"
    hidefocus="on"
    unselectable="on"
    id="TabBar:PolicyTab"
    tabindex="0"
    componentid="TabBar:PolicyTab"
    style="right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 207px;"
>
    <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-split x-btn-split-right">
        <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-text x-btn-button-center">
            <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small" style=""></span>
            <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small"><span class="g-underlined">P</span>olicy</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
<span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnWrap" data-ref="btnWrap" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-wrap-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-split x-btn-split-right">
    <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-text x-btn-button-center">
        <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small" style=""></span>
        <span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small"><span class="g-underlined">P</span>olicy</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

This has been my target
`TabBar:PolicyTab-btnWrap`  but I've also tried `#TabBar\:PolicyTab-btnEl`. I found what the menu is in the HTML but I can't refernce it until its been "viewed" but I cannot make it appear.Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.

also I should add:

```
<span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnEl" data-ref="btnEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" style="" class="x-btn-button x-btn-button-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small x-btn-text    x-btn-button-center "><span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnIconEl" data-ref="btnIconEl" role="presentation" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-icon-el x-btn-icon-el-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small  " style=""></span><span id="TabBar:PolicyTab-btnInnerEl" data-ref="btnInnerEl" unselectable="on" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-gw-top-menu-toolbar-small"><span class="g-underlined">P</span>olicy</span>
::after
</span>
```

When I hover the mouse in DevTools over the ::after it highlights the drop down arrow I want but I cant reference it & "click" on it.

Comment: Please add your vba code and url if possible

Comment: Was the html copied correctly from source?

Comment: QHarr, thank you. I'm not in the office now. the Vba though is pretty simple. It works on many parts of the webpage, but not this element. Set HTMLElement = IE.Document.queryselector("whicheverelementI'mtryinghere") kind of thing. The website is private. Here is a pastebin of the code for the whole top header. https://pastebin.com/aG7DJ45x I also edited my answer.

Comment: And in that pastebin code which element do you need to click on?

Comment: That's the question. TabBar:PolicyTab-btnEl this is close to the element. The ::after that comes right after it, highlights the down arrow when I mouse over it in DevTools. But the :: after I cannot reference and BtnEl although my code finds it, click has no effect.

Comment: you cannot target ::after I'm afraid. Are you sure there isn't an actual element to target?

Comment: There should be, but i've tried what I think is all of them. TabBar:PolicyTab-btnWrap. abBar:PolicyTab-btnIconEl. TabBar:PolicyTab-btnIconEl. TabBar:PolicyTab-btnInnerEl.TabBar:PolicyTab. IconEl & InnerEl I thought might be them. My last thing I'll try monday will be dispatch event with click. although I tried on btnWrap but i'll try on All of them.  TabBar:PolicyTab-btnEl has the :: after so that might be the best target.

Comment: Its also the right side of TabBar:PolicyTab-btnWrap that I want not necessarily the drop down arrow. I did some testing with the mouse & anywhere on the right half gets the menu to drop.

Comment: So far I've been unsuccessful. Every time I "click" on an element of that split button it triggers the default behavior of going to the last record, but I have not been able to emulate the mouse click on the right side of the button which causes the menu to descend.